# Git inserted many <<<<< error messages into my sourcecode

Tags: git

I'm very new to using Git, so many things escape me. Yesterday I tried to do a *git revert* operation which failed, and it generated some error about merging or stuff. I found a workaround this, by cloning my repository and then using

$ git reset --hard SHA1_HASH

to get back to a previous commit. Unfortunately, now my code is peppered with lots of additional stuff like

```
<<<<<<<<<<<< HEAD
//some stuff
=======
//other stuff
>>>>>>>>>>>> parent of 1ae3953... Removed duplicate folders
```

How do I remove this stuff? I'm having a really hard time going through all my files and deleting them by hand... Is there a way for Git to remove it?

EDIT: Turns out the marker became part of my code somehow during some commit. How do I ensure in the future, if some pull or revert failed, Git would not insert these markers into my code? Is there some kind of -flag for it?

Comment: Sounds like some conflicts ended up in your code during merge or revert...

Comment: It would be nice if `git-add` could (be configured to) refuse to operate on conflicted files that contain conflict markers, since this seems to be an easy mistake.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's a merge conflict marker, which is added when you do something like a `git pull` and the incoming changes can't be merged automatically with your own changes.  It shows you where you need to manually resolve a conflict.

`git reset --hard` doesn't add markers like that, it resets everything to match the commit you specified.  If you see conflict markers after doing `git reset --hard`, you probably neglected to resolve a conflict at some point in the past, and inadvertently committed them.

Comment: The "inadvertently committed" bit here is really important. You need to be aware that your computer can't always merge everything for you, and that those merge conflict messages are telling you that you have some work to do.

Comment: Is there a way to turn off the markers option next time a merge/pull/revert failed? I don't want stuff being added everytime it fails. =|

Comment: @cardin, no that is git's way of saying "i don't know what to do here, you need to change it so it's correct."  After all, a program doesn't always know what the user wants to do.

it's an annoyance when you have merge errors, but it's best to make sure your code is correct when there is one instead of just not having them thrown at all.

Comment: @dtan but a lot of times i type commands i don't really understand, just to try it out. That tends to be a lot of errors (and markers). Throwing errors are good but, can Git just give the error in the terminal only and not in the sourcecode? It's like Git saying: "there's some problem in your code, so I'm not merging it. Btw I messed up your code. Good luck."

Comment: I don't think this will throw the error in the terminal, but have you tried `--dry-run`?

Comment: @Cardin, it's Git saying "I merged the parts that I can do automatically, and marked the parts that you need to do manually".  `git status` will show you which files have conflicts so you know where to look for the conflict markers.  It's not an error, it just means that some human attention is needed before the merge can finish.  If you change your mind and want to abort the whole thing, `git reset` will undo the changes from the incomplete merge.

Comment: @Cardin: No, it's giving you the best possible setup for performing the rest of the merge. The alternative is for you to never perform the merge. Git assumes that when you tell it to merge, you have some desire to do so. `git reset --merge` will toss out the entire merge and leave you back where you started.

Comment: @Wyzard, this is a bit late, but in this situation you can fix the markers, add the changed files to the index, and then amend your commit.  You just edit the files like normal, use `git add` to add them, and then `git commit --amend`, which will change your commit to include the new files in the index.  (You can also change the commit message if you want.)  You shouldn't do this if you've already pushed the commit, but if the commit is still only on your PC then it's safe.