# How do I mark conflicts as resolved in the git GUI tool?

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge changes from a feature branch into the development branch of my project. I use both the GitHub GUI app for Mac OS X as well as the command line to manage my git projects. For a long time, I've been able to manage merge conflicts with the command line, but I have no idea if and how to do the same thing in the GUI client. Even if I resolve the conflicts in BBEdit and then click the "Commit" button, it still says:

```
•error: 'commit' is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree,
hint: and then use 'git add/rm <file>' as
hint: appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit,
hint: or use 'git commit -a'.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
 (128)
```

How can I resolve this without resorting to the command line?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any merge markers left? (merge markers as illustrated in http://stackoverflow.com/q/4755059/6309)

Comment: Yes. I removed the merge markers and saved the file, but the yellow "conflict" badge still appears next to the file in the GitHub GUI list.

Comment: You have saved the file, but did you **add** the file in the git index? Only then the GitHub GUI should consider that merged file as "resolved" instead of "conflict".

Comment: How do I "add" the file from the GUI? I'm familiar with `git add` from the command line, but as far as I know, "adding" in the GUI is just checking the box next to the file, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. However, it would be interesting to check how "GitHub for Mac" consider those files if you "`git add`" them from the command line (you can open a shell from the Github for Mac, or install git if the shell complains of a missing git: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17131161/6309)

Comment: Maybe this will be useful?: [Resolving merge conflicts](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts). "Once you've resolved the conflict, make sure that you've removed all the remaining conflict markers and save your changes. If you've experienced a merge conflict while syncing, you can go ahead and click "Mark Resolved." If the conflict occurred locally, simply make another commit to finish resolving it."

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  I modified the conflict file in Dreamweaver but the conflict still appears in the GUI.  The only way to resolve was doing a git add from the command line.  In this case I opened the file directly from Dreamweaver.  Next, I recreated the conflict situation but this time opened the file in Dreamweaver from the Git GUI and resolved the conflict.  The GUI recognized the resolution and allowed me to commit WITHOUT using git add from the command line.

The short answer, use the Git GUI to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

May not be answer you were looking for but, I had same problem and I did `git add .` and `git commit -m "commit message here"` and then `git push` from git bash CLI instead from code IDE CLI and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

if use “git mergetool” to start the beyond compare 3 ,when resolve the conflict and close the beyond compare 3, the file with conflict has been marked resolved and can be commit.
but,if use "git gui" to start the beyond compare 3,when resolve the conflict and close the beyond compare 3,the git gui also remind  "conflict".Then ,you should click the file in the left column  to mark the resolution.